# XOR arithmetically defined with operations for natural numbers (or integers)

Tags: python, xor, arithmetic-expressions

I was reviewing other posts to find an Arithmetic way for XOR and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293278/mathematical-arithmetic-representation-of-xor), but cannot apply to **natural numbers** in python3.

The trivial way:

```
a = 12
b = 5
a^b ===> 9
```

Using the other posts formula:

```
a = 12
b = 5
a + b - a*b*(1 + a + b - (a*b))   ===> 2537
```

Another option:

```
a = 12
b = 5
(a-b)**2   ===> 49
```

Off course, all the previous is working well as the trivial way if a and b are zero or one, like the other posts said, but...

Is there a function for getting XOR with **natural numbers** in a more Arithmetic way?

**UPDATE**:
Using the code of the response, I built the arithmetic fórmulas in a more mathematical way, just getting more clear the question and the answer. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: As that post indicates, that second one is only for bit numbers (1 or 0)

Comment: And, I think, only to indicate whether they are both non-zero or not, not to give a bit-wise element.  Since XOR is only defined for base 2 numbers, I don't think it's actually possible to emulate it using arithmetic expressions (without just breaking them down entirely using divides and mods to break it into a vector of numbers)

Comment: The answer to the question is "no".  The AND, OR, and XOR operators are, by definition, operating on bits.  There's no decimal/arithmetic equivalent.

Comment: XOR is basically binary addition, without carry.  So adding the two numbers, then subtracting what would have been carried during addition would work.  And carry happens when both numbers have a 1 bit in the same place, which is the same as the AND operation (shifted left by one bit).  So `a + b - ((a & b) << 1)` - not sure if that's a good enough answer, as there's still a bitwise operation in there.

Comment: How much "more Arithmetic" do you want it to be?

Comment: You can extract individual bits with integer division/modulo by 2. So you can perform any bitwise operation by doing that in a loop.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz if possible without bit wise operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we have to settle on a definition of "arithmetic." Britannica says it's the "*branch of mathematics in which numbers, relations among numbers, and observations on numbers are studied and used to solve problems*".

With these ground rules, the following are legal in addition to the usual `+-*/`:

- Integer division
- Modulo (remainder of division)
- Max and comparison (relations among numbers)

These can be exploited to arithmetically "bit-shift".

The following meets the given criteria:

```
# By the problem statement, we're dealing with Natural numbers (Z+). No need to check for negatives.

def numBits(x):
    acc = 0
    while x > 0:
        x //= 2
        acc += 1
    return acc

def xor(a, b):
    acc = 0
    pos = 1
    for i in range(numBits(max(a, b))):
        acc += ((a + b) % 2) * pos
        a //= 2
        b //= 2
        pos *= 2

    return acc

# Prints 9
print(xor(12, 5))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9BCsIwEEXXySk@iJDUQqtuRKgLz@AFUo0asElJI6anj5mKFnd/3sz8P9OP4e7sNqWLvsI@u6MJg4hyz5k6n9Gg5ux1Nw@NiAPqjFlEVTXYZEUTqwZrzrwOT2@RAedkFJ0XqkT759O7AdP01XkYGAuv7E2Lb2qn4mdJ0trXXQiFVYZYYiNRILtQ83dE@1PkX5D8v2eBkx4Cp9A4h@4og9g4s1hiwqz3xgYqx3J6hZSUKb0B)

"Arithmetic" could include exponentiation and logarithms to save some typing as well, but I kept it down to the more basic operations.

If you're looking for something more single-formula, if you know the bit-width, n, of your numbers beforehand, you can unroll the above loops to a sum of n-terms:

```
def xor(a, b):
    return ((a + b) % 2) + ((a // 2 + b // 2) % 2) * 2 + ... + ((a // 2 ** n + b // 2 ** n) % 2) * 2 ** n
```

Comment: That's just what I'm searching. Thank you very much