# What is Mathematical equation for (x * a) XOR (x *b) XOR (x *c)?

Tags: math, formula, xor

**The question is**; how to calculate `(x * a) XOR (x *b) XOR (x *c)`?

**Definitions are**; x, a, b, c are all large hexadecimal numbers known by default.

**Solutions are**; to calculate `x*a`, `x*b`, `x*c` and then bitwise xor them. the problem for this solution is that bitwise operation is binary logic arithmetic operation and its way too slow for large numbers and you should convert any number to Binary base and not an option to do without computer, at least for solution I'm looking for.

**second solution** was provided in this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385389/xor-using-mathematical-operators), were: `(a − b)²` or `a + b - ab(1 + a + b - ab)` that all are wrong and you can test them yourself.

**Now, My question is**; is there any mathematical equation for XOR rather than bitwise operations? I searched everywhere but I couldnt find any working example of such thing.

***A bit of understanding***: XOR is bitwise adding 2 or more numbers without including carry bit in calculations. This means all odd TRUE(1) numbers will result in TRUE(1), and others to FALSE(0).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you pleas provide your code and its timing.

Comment: And please what do mean by _large_ number? What is approximate order?

Comment: @YuriGinsburg what do you mean by code and its timing? I'm looking for math equation. large numbers are just an example, I want math equation to include in my calculations.

Comment: Please review your post for formatting. I bet that "to calculate x*a, x*b, x*c" is not what you meant to show there. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help In the first line of your post you got it right I think.

Comment: Please review "This means all odd ... numbers will result in TRUE(1), and others to FALSE(0)". If you commit to that, answering your question is possible and easy. If you instead expect the result of your calculation to be a multidigit number, then the answer is much less easy and probably impossible within the scope of what you hope for.

Comment: To phrase alternatively: Do you expect the result of `(x * a) XOR (x *b) XOR (x *c)` to be TRUE/FALSE? Or do you expect that to be a number 0, 1, 2, .... large?

Comment: Another phrasing of the same question: Does your code contain something like `if((x * a) XOR (x *b) XOR (x *c)) {} else {}`? (I am a C person...). Or does it contain something like `printf("%d is the numerical result of the operation.\n", (x * a) ^ (x *b) ^ (x *c));` ?

Comment: @Yunnosch i've edited and fixed multiplication. and I'm looking for; if an equation exist to be done with only 4 basic operands (+-*/)

Comment: I bet a dinner (I select the restaurant) that it is not possible with the "standard" math operators `+ * / -`. It might be possible with the gallois-2 math (aka bitwise) operators `AND OR NOT` applied to single bits. If that is not an option I am out of this. What I want to impress on you is that you are mixing two different kinds of math. The "usual decimal", or hexadecimal, where operators on one digit potentially affect the next digit is the first kind of math.

Comment: The second kind is gallois-2 math, on a different set of numbers and with different operators which do NOT potentially touch next. Also known as "bitwise".

Comment: I am not a math person. If there is one out there and able to correct me, I will happily try to learn.

Comment: You've completely misunderstood what [your linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2385389/238704) is about. That question is about XORing two bits using the standard arithmetic operators. Your question is completely different. Also, this appears to be an X-Y problem.

Answer (score 0):

> bitwise operation is binary logic arithmetic operation and its way too slow for large numbers

Typically binary arithmetic is among the fastest operations you can do. The XOR should be much faster than the multiplication, for example. Also, of your numbers are in hexadecimal, you can process one byte at a time, or one hex digit at a time, so the size of the numbers affects the computation time only linearly.

> and you should convert any number to Binary base and not an option to do without computer, at least for solution I'm looking for.

What, you are looking for a solution without a computer? That sounds like a very unusual constraint for a question on Stack Overflow, so you might want to go into more detail about what your use case is.

Even if a human is to perform the operation in their head, I'd still maintain that with enough practice, XOR should be faster than most other operations. But getting that practice may take time.

> Is there any mathematical equation for XOR rather than bitwise operations?

Well, sometimes people use ℤ₂[X], i.e. write the sequence of bits as a polynomial with coefficients in {0, 1}. That way the XOR becomes a simple addition, but it's no longer an addition of simple numbers. And it doesn't change anything about how to actually compute things, it's just a different notation.

The carry-less addition you get from the polynomial representation doesn't work very well with the carry-observing multiplication you have in you equation. So I don't see you gaining much from a switch of notation.

Comment: I doubt you can rewrite as `x * (a XOR b XOR c)`, consider x=3, a=1, b=2, c=3: 

3*(1^2^3)=3*0=0, but 
(3*1)^(3*2)^(3*3)=3^6^9=12

Comment: @maxim1000 you are right, I've mixed up addition as a polynomial with multiplication as a number. Will delete that section.